# Pass a render function as a parameter to a partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to build a generic modal partial view using Rails 5 and Bootstrap modal. To render this partial view, I want to be able to do something like this:

```html
<%= render 'shared/bootstrap_modal', modal_id: 'modalId', modal_title: 'Modal title', modal_body: <%= render 'user_list', users: users %> %>
```

In other words, I have a "modal body" section in the generic bootstrap_modal partial view I have created. I would like to essentially pass in a render function via the modal_body parameter so I can render whatever I want in the modal body. Is that possible with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had some bad syntax, if you change your inner `render` to something like this, it works for me

```
<%= render 'shared/bootstrap_modal', modal_id: 'modalId', modal_title: 'Modal title', modal_body: render('user_list', users: users) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `render_to_string` method ([docs](https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/render_to_string)).

Something like this should work

`<%= render 'shared/bootstrap_modal', 
              modal_id: 'modalId', 
              modal_title: 'Modal title',
              modal_body: render_to_string('user_list', 
                                           locals: {users: users}) %>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this right after you posted, but I had some weird side effects with this solution. The answer I accepted works perfectly for what I needed.

Comment: ah, okay. Sorry about that. The accepted solution is definitely better.